# Symfony Embed a Collection of Forms do not display the form

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony5

I try to embed a collection of forms like in the doc but for some unknown reason the collection of form is not displaying. (The rest of the form works)

LigneFfType :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('dateFFrais', DateType::class, [
            'widget' => 'single_text',
        ])
        ->add('quantite', IntegerType::class)
        ->add('typeFF', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => TypeFF::class
        ])
        ->add('fraisForfait', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => FraisForfaitType::class,
            'allow_add' => true
        ));
}
```

FraisForfaitType :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('label')
        ->add('prix')
    ;
}
```

my view :

```
...
{% for frais in form.fraisForfait %}
    {{ form_row(frais.label) }}
{% endfor %}
```

I don't think it has anything to do with it but here are the entity relationships
LigneFf :

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\FraisForfait", inversedBy="ligneFf")
 */
private $fraisForfait;
```

FraisForfait :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\LigneFf", mappedBy="fraisForfait")
 */
private $ligneFf;
```

Comment: you should use some javascript code 
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

Comment: That is to say ? to do what ?

Comment: to create a button, on each click a new form row will be added to the form (DOM)

Comment: If you inspect your code, you should see a data-prototype around the "fraisForfait" input. Then, look a @hous message to have more information! Everything is in the documentation! :) (https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop on your CollectionType.

Symfony will handle it by itself:

```
{{ form_row(form.fraisForfait) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic form collection requires a javascript snippet to work.

If you just need to see your field rendered, you need to add one or some child entities into the parent entity in the controller, like that:

```
$fraisForfait = new FraisForfait();
$fraisForfait->setLabel(...);
$fraisForfait->setPrix(...);

$ligneFf->getFraisForfait()->add($fraisForfait);

// create the form, and then render it
```